# Can I implement onboard LED blinks as "status" on Umqtt .wait_msg() on Raspeberry Pi Pico W running Micropython?

Tags: mqtt, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm trying to let the LED keep blinking while waiting in the "wait_msg()" function. can I achieve this by uasycncio, _thread, or modification on the main loop in the module? And how?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
client.check_msg()
led.toggle()
time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: OMG this works perfectly. And this solves my other problem as well. Thank you so much!